# Event click owl-item recém add

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho varios owlcarousel2 ao realizar alguns teste eu percebi o seguinte o item ou vários itens que são adicionados ao carousel usando o `add.owl.carousel` nao são dectados no event de click que segue abaixo, se eu atualizar a pagina o click funciona normalmente, mas ao atualiza a pagina o carousel é preenchido com outro evento, mas usa a mesma estrutura html, inspecionei os itens recém adicionas e não vi nada de diferente. Sou novato em jquery, pode ser que esqueci de algo importante. Os script estão todos no final da pagina. Alguém já viu algo semelhante?

Meu carousel tem esse modelo, só que dentro de cada item há uma estrutura.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Event de click em um item do carousel

```
$('.owl-item').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('marked');
    $(this).siblings('.owl-item').removeClass('marked');        
});
```

Função que insere itens nos carouseils, ja que são 5. A inserção é bem sucedida.

```
function insertItemCarousel(DataItens, list){
    list.map((day) =>{
        let html = `
        <div class="item" data-id="${day}-${DataItens._id}">
            <div class="itens-Interno">
                <div class="imgdiv" >
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="${DataItens.image.replace(/"/g,"")}">                      
                </div>
                <div class="textdiv">
                    <a class="categoria">${DataItens.categoria}</a>
                    <h5 class="NomePrato">${DataItens.nomeprato}</h5>
                    <a class="descricao">${DataItens.descricao}</a><br>
                    <div class="botoesAction">
                        <button type="button">Excluir</button>
                        <button type="button">Editar</button>              
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>`;
    $(`.owl-carousel.${day}`).owlCarousel('add', html).owlCarousel('update');
    })  
}
```

Comment: Tente usar o evento desta forma: `$(document).on('click', '.owl-item', function() {`

Comment: Vlw, era isso mesmo, obrigado. Responda a pergunta que dou como resposta certa.

Comment: Valeu! Vou marcar como duplicata mesmo, porque já teve perguntas que abordaram o mesmo problema. Abs!

Comment: Opa sem problema.